# In Linux How do I create a folder inside folder from terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command

I want to create a folder tree like below

```
2006
    -seattle
           -plans
                 -marketing
```

Is there a linux command to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Following worked for me. Thanks to [linfo](http://www.linfo.org/make_directory_tree.html)

```
mkdir -p 2006/seattle/plans/marketing
```

However there could be more effective ones.

Answer (score 2):

To create sub-folders in a Terminal, we generally prefer

```
mkdir -p h/{hh,hhh/hhhh}
```

Output Folder Structure

```
h/

hh hhh/

       hhhh
```

Comment: Yes for sub folder, its a simple way.